# Why is RelativeLayout not enforcing layout_alignLeft with layout_centerInParent view?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

**Why (the hell) isn't the `RadioButton` left edge correctly aligned with the gray square left edge?**

Is this some kind of limitation or bug of `RelativeLayout` preventing from aligning a view to another view centered in parent ?

What would be the cleanest workaround?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/square"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/square"
        android:text="Radio button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: screenshot from AS 2.2.3 Layout Editor. Android API: 25]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your `View` and `RadioButton` in a `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/square"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:text="Radio button"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    />
```

Comment: Indeed, setting the RelativeLayout width as match_parent solves the alignment issue. But of course it also changes the behavior of this RelativeLayout inside its parent. I *need* the RelativeLayout width to wrap_content as it is part of bigger layout.

Comment: Indeed, the trick of using an extra `RelativeLayout` is giving the expected result. Though I don't really get your explanation "otherwise android:layout_alignLeft="@id/square" is trying to align it to the left of your square `View."

Comment: Sorry I was in a rush. Check my original post. I updated it to include a more descriptive answer. It also includes updated code, which allows you to remove the extra `RelativeLayout`. Let me know if you need any further clarification. Thanks

Comment: I think your previous answer using an extra `RelativeLayout` was better. It is the only workaround that does not change the initial layout. Please revert your edit so that I can accept it. There are 2 issues with your current answer: #1. Fixed width of 300dip was just to simplify the example, the real View is actually a variable width TextView, which is why I need the parent layout to wrap_content.  #2. The post you cite is about a simpler issue: alignLeft conflicting with alignParentRight in the *same* view.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @Sébastien I've rolled back my answer.

Answer (score 1):

due to relative layout width wrap_content

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

<View
    android:id="@+id/square"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

<RadioButton
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/square"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/square"
    android:text="Radio button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: Indeed, setting the RelativeLayout width as match_parent solves the alignment issue. But of course it also changes the behavior of this RelativeLayout inside its parent. I *need* the RelativeLayout width to wrap_content as it is part of bigger layout.

Comment: in that case relative layout width should equal to the holo green light view, which is max width required

Answer (score 0):

`RadioButton` element is missing `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to keep it in center of the screen or use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` below code is of centerInParent

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">

  <View
      android:id="@+id/square"
      android:layout_width="200dip"
      android:layout_height="200dp"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

  <RadioButton
      android:layout_alignLeft="@id/square"
      android:text="Radio button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

  <View
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is not the expected layout, the RadioButton should be aligned with left edge of square.